# xpath exclude sub element on main content

Tags: xpath

i have this code that extract all content inside entry-content div

```bash
//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "entry-content")]/*
```

insde the entry content div i also have this code

```xml
<figure id="attachment_81870" aria-describedby="caption-attachment-81870" style="width: 706px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
    <a href="https://abc.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/AMX-special-4.jpg">
        <img data-attachment-id="81870"  data-orig-file="https://abc.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/AMX-special-4.jpg" data-orig-size="1600,1067" data-comments-opened="0"   class="size-large wp-image-81870 jetpack-lazy-image" src="https://abc.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/AMX-special-4-706x471.jpg" alt="" width="706" height="471" >
        <noscript>
            <img data-lazy-fallback="1" data-attachment-id="81870" data-permalink="https://abc.it/2023/02/17/the-italian-air-force-celebrates-80th-anniversary-of-103rd-gruppo-with-special-colored-amx/amx-special-4/" data-orig-file="https://abc.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/AMX-special-4.jpg" data-orig-size="1600,1067" data-comments-opened="0"  class="size-large wp-image-81870" src="https://abc.it/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/AMX-special-4-706x471.jpg" alt="" width="706" height="471" sizes="(max-width: 706px) 100vw, 706px"/>
        </noscript>
    </a>
    <figcaption id="caption-attachment-81870" class="wp-caption-text">Another look at the Indians special. (Image credit: Claudio Tramontin)</figcaption>
</figure>
```

can one extrat only the data inside the noscript tag? what is the xpath code that I need to add to my code to get this data?

i try this but not work

```bash
//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "entry-content")]/*[contains(.,"noscript")]
```

Comment: `contains()` looks at element content. Try `/*[name()="noscript"]`

Comment: like this? //div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "entry-content")]/*[name()="noscript"]

Comment: yes, that would be the full expression